# how to convert array to image ( png, jpg )?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to convert values ​​from an array into an image

In this example it would be a 4x4 image, the colors are in hex and each list within the array is one line of the image and each hex value is a pixel with its corresponding color.

```
array=[[[ff0000, ff0000, ff0000, ff0000]#red
        [ff1bec, ff1bec, ff1bec, ff1bec]#purple
        [1bf7ff, 1bf7ff, 1bf7ff, 1bf7ff]#light blue
        [1bff1b, 1bff1b, 1bff1b, 1bff1b]#green
        ]
```

**generating an image like this:**

[4x4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwO0m.png)

Comment: a) `ff0000` is not a valid token in Python, did you mean `0xff0000`? b) Why are the pixels three deep, shouldn't they be two deep (e.g. array=[[ff0000, ff0000, ff0000, ff0000], ..])

Comment: sorry the ignorance is that I'm new in python, I started studying python to extend my arduino projects, well the concept of the project is that already having the required data (pixel colors 0Xff0000) so that the length of bytes in the list is equivalent to the length of each line of image(pixels) I would like to turn this into a jpg or png image no matter what format I have tried using some libraries but without success(I am new)